# How to find if my Amazon EC2 instance is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am newbie to this and this may be very easy question but I am running a Amazon EC2 instance and I don't know if my running instance is 32 bit or 64 bit.

**My Question**

Is there any way to find if my instance is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This should work for any linux instance. On the terminal type the following command:

```
> uname -a
Linux domU-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX 3.2.20-1.29.6.amzn1.i686 
      #1 SMP Tue Jun 12 01:20:33 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

That last "i386" indicates that it's 32-bit; "x86_64" indicates 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

uname -m

```
   -m, --machine
          print the machine hardware name
```

e.g.
$ uname -m

x86_64