# Error - '''unsupported architecture for instance type "t2.micro": i386''' while creating a Kubernetes Cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli, kubectl, kops

I am new to this platform and this is my second question. For one month, I have been trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster using AWS unsuccessfully. But every day, I get a new error, but this time, I could not solve this error.

I am using Kali Linux in Virtual Box with Windows as a host. I am following a tutorial from Udemy for the setup.

1. I have installed Kops, Kubectl, and AWSCli successfully.
2. I have configured the keys correctly, using AWS configure (For learning purpose, I have given my user full administrator rights)
3. I created the S3 bucket (Gave it public access)
4. Now to create the hosted zone, I used AWS Route 53.
   [Here are specs of my hosted zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPXvz.png)
5. Since, I do not have a domain, I bought a free subdomain from freenom.com and configured the nameservers correctly.
   [Free domain configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt8Nf.png)
6. After that, I created a pair of keys using ssh-keygen for logging in to the cluster.
7. In the end, I am running this command,

```
kops create cluster --name=kubernetes.hellaswell.ml --state=s3://kops-state-crap --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro --dns-zone=kubernetes.hellaswell.ml                                   1 ⚙
I0418 22:49:10.855151   12216 new_cluster.go:238] Inferred "aws" cloud provider from zone "eu-west-1a"
I0418 22:49:10.855313   12216 new_cluster.go:962]  Cloud Provider ID = aws
I0418 22:49:12.604015   12216 subnets.go:180] Assigned CIDR 172.20.32.0/19 to subnet eu-west-1a

unable to determine machine architecture for InstanceGroup "master-eu-west-1a": unsupported architecture for instance type "t2.micro": i386
```

Comment: What AMI are you using?

Comment: I am using Kali Linux with which I am accessing AWS and configuring my cluster. Regarding AMI, it's t2.micro. (Sorry, but I think that is the image I am mentioning in my "kops create cluster" command. Otherwise, I do not know we have to specify it somewhere else too).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend going below the default instance types (t3.medium at the moment). You will most likely end up with a cluster that cannot fit the base workloads or that reacts very slowly. Also, if you have been struggling for as long as a month, you may consider joining the kops slack channels for faster feedback loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instance types should now be supported by kOps if there are 64-bit variabts available.

The fix can be found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/pull/11463

Answer (score 2):

> unsupported architecture for instance type "t2.micro": i386

Some EC2 t2.micro instances are actually 32-bit machines. See [How to find if my Amazon EC2 instance is 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565748/213269).

Your Kubernetes container probably contains a binary that is compiled for 64-bit machines. I suggest that you choose a different EC2 instance type, e.g. t3.small.

Comment: But in the kops create cluster command, there is no option to specify 64-bit or 32-bit. I will use t3.small in the command and will update you, if it works.

Comment: kOps binaries are 64-bit only. There are no 32-bit binaries available.

Comment: t3.small is not working. It's giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4523789/ole-markus-with , Your suggestion of using t3.medium was indeed helpful.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ kops create cluster --name=kube.hellaswell.ml --state=s3://kops-state-crap --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.small --master-size=t2.small --dns-zone=kube.hellaswell.ml
I0419 20:18:36.700942    2086 new_cluster.go:238] Inferred "aws" cloud provider from zone "eu-west-1a"
I0419 20:18:36.700999    2086 new_cluster.go:962]  Cloud Provider ID = aws
I0419 20:18:37.938892    2086 subnets.go:180] Assigned CIDR 172.20.32.0/19 to subnet eu-west-1a

unable to determine machine architecture for InstanceGroup "master-eu-west-1a": unsupported architecture for instance type "t2.small": i386
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ kops create cluster --name=kube.hellaswell.ml --state=s3://kops-state-crap --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t2.medium --master-size=t2.medium --dns-zone=kube.hellaswell.ml                                             1 ⨯
I0419 20:18:58.255708    2094 new_cluster.go:238] Inferred "aws" cloud provider from zone "eu-west-1a"
I0419 20:18:58.255834    2094 new_cluster.go:962]  Cloud Provider ID = aws
I0419 20:18:59.282307    2094 subnets.go:180] Assigned CIDR 172.20.32.0/19 to subnet eu-west-1a

unable to determine machine architecture for InstanceGroup "master-eu-west-1a": unsupported architecture for instance type "t2.medium": i386
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ kops create cluster --name=kube.hellaswell.ml --state=s3://kops-state-crap --zones=eu-west-1a --node-count=2 --node-size=t3.medium --master-size=t3.medium --dns-zone=kube.hellaswell.ml                                             1 ⨯
I0419 20:20:47.323068    2103 new_cluster.go:238] Inferred "aws" cloud provider from zone "eu-west-1a"
I0419 20:20:47.323286    2103 new_cluster.go:962]  Cloud Provider ID = aws
I0419 20:20:49.012132    2103 subnets.go:180] Assigned CIDR 172.20.32.0/19 to subnet eu-west-1a
I0419 20:20:51.943459    2103 create_cluster.go:726] Using SSH public key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Previewing changes that will be made:

I0419 20:21:03.446344    2103 executor.go:111] Tasks: 0 done / 77 total; 43 can run
W0419 20:21:05.094898    2103 vfs_castore.go:604] CA private key was not found
I0419 20:21:05.095112    2103 executor.go:111] Tasks: 43 done / 77 total; 16 can run
I0419 20:21:06.137672    2103 executor.go:111] Tasks: 59 done / 77 total; 16 can run
I0419 20:21:07.358255    2103 executor.go:111] Tasks: 75 done / 77 total; 2 can run
I0419 20:21:08.538778    2103 executor.go:111] Tasks: 77 done / 77 total; 0 can run
Will create resources:
  AutoscalingGroup/master-eu-west-1a.masters.kube.hellaswell.ml
```

I am new to AWS and Kubernetes, Pardon my curiosity, But I wanted to know, How do others are able to create clusters with t2.micro. I have seen tutorials on Udemy and this blog too https://www.scottyfullstack.com/blog/setting-up-a-free-tier-kubernetes-cluster-with-kop/